# My C++ program crashes on this function?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner programmer(Just started) and I'm writing some code for a binary search tree for fun.
For some reason, whenever I call this append function my program crashes. It has to do with one of the two functions itself, not anything else in the header file or my source file which includes main(). By the way Leaf is just a struct with an int value, and two Leaf pointers named left and right.

This crashes with no output error.

```
Leaf* BinarySearchTree::GetLeaf(int x,Leaf*a)
{
 int key = a->value;
 cout <<key<<"\n";
 if(x > key)
 {
  if(a->right == NULL)
  {
   Leaf* newleaf = new Leaf();
   newleaf->value = x;
   a->right = newleaf;
   return newleaf;
  }
 else if (a->right != NULL)
 {
  return a->right;
 }
}
else if(x< key)
{
 if(a->left == NULL)
 {
   Leaf* newleaf = new Leaf();
   newleaf->value = x;
   a->left = newleaf;
   return newleaf;
 }
 else if (a->left != NULL)
 {
   return a->left;
 }
}
else if(x == key)
{
 //tbc
}
}
void BinarySearchTree::Append(int x)
{
  if(root != NULL)
  {
    Leaf* current = root;
    while(current->value != x)
    {
        current = BinarySearchTree::GetLeaf(x,current);
        cout<<"value: "<<
        current->value;
    }
  }
  else
  {
   cout <<" No ROOT!";return;
  }
}
```

If you want to see my main (source) file, go here(Since I don't want to flood this post)
http://pastebin.com/vrh7KkMm

If you want to see the rest of the header file, where these two functions are located,
http://pastebin.com/ZGWewPdV

Comment: `I'm a beginner programmer(Just started) and I'm writing some code for a binary search tree for fun` Why not start with something simpler?

Comment: How do you call the append function?

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to use a debugger.  It will show you where the crash is and allow you to understand the circumstances that caused the crash.

Comment: Think what happens if `GetLeaf` does not find anything.

Comment: Also, to make your life easier (which will also allow you to learn faster), I suggest you adopt some common indentation style (4 spaces is common in C++ code), and use a code formatter or autoindenter (any IDE worth anything can do this) to keep you code tidy. It helps in finding bugs too, such as mismatched `if`...`else` pairs.

Comment: Thanks guys, also, shouldn't it automatically return a NULL pointer if there is nothing it finds?

Answer (score 1):

In your BinarySearchTree constuctor, you start accessing root without having allocated memory for it first. This may be your crash. Try adding

```
root = new Leaf()
```

at the start of the constructor.

Edit - More information:

C++ does not automatically set values for your member variables, you normally need to initialize them by hand. (c++11 does allow you to do it in the declaration). This means that any variable that you don't set to a value will have a garbage value in it. If you use this garbage value as a pointer, you will most likely get a crash.

In your case, one of the initial problems is that the LinkedList class did not initialize its root member variable in the constructor before starting to reference it.

BinarySearchTree has the same problem.

Learning to use the debugger is one of the best things you can do when learning to program. It lets you step through your code one line at a time and look at the value of each variable. This makes i easy to see where things aren't going as you planned. Which debugger you use depends on your platform.

Comment: He covered this by "if (root != NULL)."

Comment: Alright, thanks. So what's the problem with me doing Leaf* root, in the BinarySearchTree class? (line 22 I believe)

Comment: Hey guys, I updated the GetLeaf function to return a at the end of the function, and it's still crashing. I know it's the getleaf function since I added some cout statements right before and right after it, and it prints the statement before but never reaches the next one.

Comment: @Silicomancer root won't be NULL as nothing sets it to NULL. It is the same issue as with the Leaf structure - the member values are not being initialized.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CQ23aB9B it only prints '1st'. Maybe this is where it crashes for some reason?

Comment: @The Dark, you are right. Of course. Ouch. He should learn about member initialization first.

Comment: I'm trying to learn, this is my first program besides hello world and printing out pointers. But I don't exactly understand what you guys are talking about quite yet. There are no computer science courses at my school so I try to self-teach myself and watch youtube tutorials ^-^. I'm probably terrible for a beginner

Comment: By the way that was the issue, I had to assign root to new Leaf() at the constructor. I'm still trying to piece together what went wrong or why I had to do that though.

Comment: No - this isn't terrible code, but you would be better off doing a bit at a time and testing it. e.g. getting the LinkedList part working before trying a binary tree. I'll update my answer with some more concrete suggestions.

Comment: My linked list works great haha. Which is confusing since in my linked list constructor, I didn't initialize it like you suggested for my BinarySearchTree ( which fixed it ).

Comment: You LinkedList didn't work for me, so you might have just got lucky with the root pointer in LinkedList pointing to memory that didn't cause a crash when it was changed. In Visual C++ debug mode it sets all class member values to 0xCDCDCDCD so that they definitely cause a crash and you can easily see which variables haven't been initialized. Other environments (and release mode code) don't do that.

Comment: Yeah I use QTCreator, a C++ IDE. I want to learn how to eventually become extremely efficient to where anything I code will work in any IDE or environment(providing it's the correct language of course). I didn't know problems like this could arise. I've only been learning programming for a couple weeks now. This whole project, believe it or not, actually took me quite some time(about a whole day).

Answer (score 0):

If `GetLeaf()` is called with `x == key` the function returns neither `nullptr` nor a valid pointer. This is a potential crash source. You need to return something sensible in any case.

UPDATE: Don't forget to initialize the Leaf structure properly in its constructor (all three members).

UPDATE2: Also initialize your root properly. I would initialize it with nullptr and change the append function in a way that it creates the very first leave if root==nullptr.

Comment: However, if I try printing something to the output at that block it does nothing. So I believe it never gets there.

Comment: Anyway fix this. Simply return the existing leaf. Also see my updated answer.